# Select all post and its comments for a specific user

Tags: mysql, sql, post, comments

i have a common situation here. I want to select all posts and its comments for a specific user. For example:

```
 1)

   Post:
     1(PostId), SomeTitle, SomeText
     2(PostId), SomeTitle, SomeText
   Comments:
     1, 1(PostId), CommentTitle, CommentText, UserId(1 - from another table)
     2, 1(PostId), CommentTitle, CommentText, UserId(1 - from another table)
     3, 2(PostId), CommentTitle, CommentText, UserId(2 - from another table)
     4, 2(PostId), CommentTitle, CommentText, UserId(2 - from another table)
```

I want to select, for example, first post in one result set and its comments in another result set by user id. In short, i would like to select all user commented posts and its comments. Can anyone help me? I was thinking to create a SP with userId and postId as parameters, but i had issues.

Comment: All posts?  Or all posts posted by a certain user?  If so, how does a post record relate to a user?

Comment: Only posts that are commented by a user. User is not able to post a new post so there is no relation between post and user table.

Comment: Tip, use `Foreign Keys` and `Joins`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This selects all posts

```
SELECT * FROM Post WHERE PostID IN (SELECT PostID FROM Comments WHERE UserID = 1);
```

This select all posts and comments:

```
SELECT * FROM Post AS P, Comments AS C WHERE C.PostID = P.PostID AND C.UserID = 1 group by C.CommentId;
```

(Not tested, but should work)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.SomeTitle, p.SomeText, c.CommentTitle, c.CommentText, c.UserID
FROM post AS p
LEFT JOIN Comments AS c
        ON c.PostId = p.PostId
```

if you want to add information about the use who commented from another table (let's call it userTable), you can add this:

```
LEFT JOIN userTable AS uT
       ON uT.UserId = c.UserId
```

This code should return you ALL the posts even these with no comments + the ones with comments associated with their respective posts

Comment: Thank you, but I need two result sets