# Get post and all its comments via single query

Tags: php, mysql

I am building a simple blog. Comments table is related to posts table w/ `comment_post_id` matching `post_id` of the post it belongs to. Now, I am trying to pull both post and all its comments via single query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM posts 
LEFT JOIN comments 
ON post_id=comment_post_id
```

With this query I get only the first comment w/ matching `comment_post_id`, and I kinda understand why. What would be a query that pulls all of them ? 
Looked at this answer [Select all post and its comments for a specific user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26265470/select-all-post-and-its-comments-for-a-specific-user), but did not work for me.

Comment: you see in your linked post that the question make included his data and you didn't see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: The only way to do that would be to reverse the tables: select all comments join on posts. You'll have multiples of the same post that way, so you'll need to adjust for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM posts 
LEFT JOIN comments 
ON posts.post_id=comments.comments_post_id 
WHERE post_id=$id
```

If post has 3 comments associated with it you get 3 rows, and each of those contain key/value pairs of the same post + one of those 3 comments.

Comment: Please keep in mind to use prepared statements or verify that $id is well formed.